# Поиск глубины дерева. Проблема с программой

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Есть задача, формально, такая: Есть дерево. Найти его глубину.

У меня есть программа. Однако, она даёт неизвестную мне ошибку. Всё что я знаю -- ошибка есть.

Формат ввода:

```
n
a[0]
a[0 + 1]
a[0 + 2]
...
a[n - 1]
```

Где n есть количество вершин, а a[i] есть номер прямого родителя вершины i.

Вот код:

```
#define pb push_back

int n;
cin >> n;

vector<vector<int> > g(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int p;
    cin >> p;

    if(p != -1) {
        g[--p].pb(i);
    }
}

vector<bool> used(n, false);
vector<int> dist(n, 1);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(!used[i]) {
        queue<int> q;
        q.push(i); used[i] = true;
        while(!q.empty()) {
            int v = q.front();
            q.pop();
            for(int to : g[v]) {
                if(used[to]) continue;
                q.push(to);
                used[to] = true;
                dist[to] = dist[v] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int mx = -INT_MAX;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mx = max(mx, dist[i]);
}

cout << mx;

return 0;
}
```

В нём я по вводным данным строю дерево, а дальше делаю классический поиск в ширину от всех непомеченных, попутно помечая их.

Тест:

```
5
-1
1
2
1
-1
```

Ответ: `3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В примере у вас несколько `-1`, поэтому задача найти не глубину дерева, а наибольшую глубину в лесу (больше одного дерева):

[image: forest]

Алгоритм: найти глубину для каждого узла и вывести наибольшую глубину. Глубина узла равна `(1 + глубина родителя)`. Глубина корня дерева равна `1`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // max_element
#include <functional> // function
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>   // istream_iterator
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // get the number of nodes
  size_t n;
  if (!(std::cin >> n))
    return 1;

  // read nodes from stdin
  std::istream_iterator<int> nodes{std::cin}, eof;
  std::vector<int> a(nodes, eof); // a[i] is the parent of an i node, -1 is root
  if (a.size() != n)
    return 2;

  // find all depths for each i node
  std::vector<int> d(n); // d[i] -- depth of i node
  std::function<int(size_t)> depth = [&](size_t i) -> int {
    if (!d[i])
      d[i] = (a[i] == -1) ? 1 : 1 + depth(a[i] - 1);
    return d[i];
  };
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    depth(i);

  // find max depth
  auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(d), std::end(d));
  std::cout << ((it == std::end(d)) ? 0 : *it);
}
```

`d[i]` кэширует результаты рекурсивных вызовов, чтобы линейная сложность осталась `O(n + max(d))`.

[Пример](https://ideone.com/B1ONFE).

Answer (score 1):

В общем, я понял проблему.

Суть в том, что надо запускать bfs не просто от *всех* непомеченых вершин, а *именно* от тех, которые являются корнями дерева. Они помечаются `-1` при вводе.

Самое простое решение - при вводе зафиксировать номера таких вершин и в bfs использовать сразу их.